# View Controller Maximum height in Storyboard Freeform mode

Tags: uiscrollview, storyboard, uikit, max, scrollview

I'm a beginner at iOS developement.
Trying to make a page which includes a large Scrollview. Problem is, as my page has many contents, I had to design them in Freeform mode. But, Freeform mode doesn't allowing me to change the height till 3000 or 4000. It allowing me just 2700. How, should i design my large page? 
Here is the screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0hpS.jpg)

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that's the case? I just added a new view controller to a storyboard, set its Size to Freeform, set its Simulated Size to Freeform at `414 x 3600`, added a label constrained to the bottom, resulting in the label having a Y coordinate of `3579`. Here is how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/0jPfGFL

Comment: I don't know what's the reason. I have opened another view controller into my another storyboard this time it taking some more heights. is a Xcode bug? or something else I'm missing??

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is. As a side note... in general, if you are building a view that large for scrolling, it is easier to manage if you use several views as subviews, or generate the whole thing via code. Trying to work with a 4000-pt tall object in Storyboard can be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've done the whole layout using tableview and seems working fine. But the idea of using subviews may the good one. If i have that earlier i could have try that..
Thanks again..